# Tezos SmartPy Developer Course video 1.2

Tags: smartpy

How do I get find the Tezos test net as opposed to the web browser smart py interface?

Regards

WF

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question a bit more?
In case you are looking for the faucet: https://faucet.tzalpha.net
In case you are looking for the test networks: https://smartpy.io/nodes

Comment: I started the Tezos SmartPy Developer Course. 

The bald gentleman walking me through on the videos is using a URL https://smartpy.io/dev/. 

When I put this into my url, it redirects me to https://smartpy.io/ide. 

The /ide doenst have the features he is teaching from. I think I set up a wallet from the facuet earlier and I have a private key.

I perceive I need "the editor" interface/website/software - I dont know the termanology, but I cant do what he is teaching b/c I cant find the interface/website/software he is teaching from.

Comment: SmartPy website has changed a bit and the faucet page is now at smartpy.io/wallet.html

Answer (score 0):

The videos apparently have an older version of what is being used by students such as myself. If you follow the directions from the instructor, and dont get to caught up on the images matching exactly, it works as is taught. Just the appearances change, which can be a bit confusing and intimidating.